# Convert data class (JSON object) to an list in kotlin

Tags: android, serialization, kotlin, data-class

I have a json object returning from a server which needs to be converted to a list

```
{"name":"xyz","times":{"x1":12.34,"x2":1.9609,"x3":4.8042}}
```

In the above json, times is a json object. I convert it to data class as below

```
@Serializable
data class ConversionRates(
    val x1: String,
    val time: Times
)
@Serializable
data class Times(val x1: Double, val x2: Double, val x3: Double)
```

But, I want Times as an listOf(String, Double) rather than as an object.

I have tried to use KSerializers but ran out of luck

Comment: Why you want to read `Times` as a list while it's an object!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure you can use `GSON` and a `Map<String, Double>`

```
data class ConversionRates(val name: String, val times: Map<String, Double>)

...

val conversionRates = GSON.fromJson(jsonString, ConversionRates::class.java)
val listRates = conversionRates.times.values
```